A man on a boat impaled by a marlin's bill
I only remember one scene from this movie: a man on a boat (small yacht?) is seemingly floating in air when he is first found in a cabin by another character. The other character freaks out because of the floating guy. Later it is discovered he has actually been impaled by the bill of a marlin in an adjoining cabin, which was thrown about by the rocking boat (perhaps during a heavy storm). The marlin's bill went through the wall and killed the man in mid-air. From the angle of the door to the cabin, it looks like he is floating.
This movie was probably made in the 70s or maybe early 80s, and it may have taken place in the Bermuda Triangle. If I remember correctly, it had a creepy horror feel to it. It was in color.

I believe you are referring to a TV movie called Satan's Triangle (1975).
From the IMDB storyline:

"and a fourth man is in an aft compartment, floating in the air. Eva
  attributes the deaths to supernatural causes, but Haig has a practical
  explanation for everything, including the man who appears to be
  floating in the air."

The scene you are referring to can be seen at 6:30 in this clip.
